# Is there a general metod to construct a fractal?

Tags: fractals

I would like to construct a fractal (traditional, self-affine, and fat fractal) with a given embedding and fractal dimension, but I don't know how to do it 
programmatically. The shape of the fractal is negligible.

Comment: Motivation? I assume you just want a graphic showing the transition between all the dimensions continuously? If so, [This](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ComparingMeasuresOfLineJaggedness/) has sliders for Wierstrass fractals.

Comment: Motivation is for example to draw or give the iteration rule of an arbitrary fractal with D = 3/2 fractal dimension and d=3 embedding dimension.

Comment: The graph of $x(t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2^{-n \cdot (2-d)} \cdot \cos(2^n \cdot t)$ with $y(t)$ and $z(t)$ being differentiable and finite and $d=3/2$ is an example.

Answer (score 4):

[Wikipedia describes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fractals_by_Hausdorff_dimension) a generalized Cantor set with parameter $0 < \gamma < 1$ giving fractal dimension

$$0 < D = \frac{-\log(2)}{\log\left(\displaystyle\frac{1-\gamma}{2}\right)} < 1$$

> Built by removing at the $m$th iteration the central interval of
>   length $\gamma\,l_{m-1}$ from each remaining segment (of length
>   $l_{m-1}=(1-\gamma)^{m-1}/2^{m-1}$). At $\gamma=\frac{1}{3}$ one obtains the
>   usual Cantor set. Varying $\gamma$ between $0$ and $1$ yields any
>   fractal dimension $0 < D < 1$

[image: Generalized Cantor set with $\gamma = 0.2$]

The Cartesian product of Cantor set fractals satisfies (Falconer "Fractal Geometry: Mathematical Foundations and Applications" chapter 7):

$$\dim(F \times G) = \dim(F) + \dim(G)$$

In an $n$-dimensional space one can fit a product of $n$ one-dimensional Cantor sets (each with $0 < D_i < 1$) to get any dimension $0<D<n$

The product of the middle-thirds Cantor set with itself, aka "Cantor dust":
[image: Cantor dust]

Comment: Thank you, the key will be that if a fractal is a direct product
of two fractals  then its dimension is the  sum
of the dimensions of the two fractals.